# SceneKitを使ってルービックキューブを回転させたい

Tags: ios, swift

SceneKitを使ってルービックキューブのアプリを作ろうとしています。

SCNNode()をつかって、ルービックキューブの27個のブロックを作ることはできたのですが、ブロックの回転で困っています。
任意のブロックの周りに相対的に回転させる方法や参考になる文献があれば教えて下さい。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

positionとpivotプロパティーを使用することによって解決することができました。
座標(x,y,z)のブロック(boxNode)を原点(0,0,0)中心に回転させたい時は以下のようにすればOkでした。あとは、runAction()を使用して、回転軸を決めてあげればOKです。

```
boxNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(-x, -y, -z)
boxNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
```